# drag and drop images from 1 div to another another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `<div>`s in which `div1` contains all the original images I want to drag and drop into `div2`, but I want to make a placeholder image appear in `div2`, say "camera.jpg", and place the original dragged image into `div3`, while keeping the original image in `div1`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dvSource img").draggable({  
            revert: "invalid",
            proxy: "clone",
            refreshPositions: true,
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
                var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
                if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
                    console.log(image + " dropped.");
                } else {
                    console.log(image + " not dropped.");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#dvDest").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
                    $("#dvDest").html("");
                }
                ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's happening so far? What's the intended behaviour? Etc...

Comment: suppose <div>1 contains 4-5 images .I want to drag that image in <div>2 one by one but i want to show a sample icon say icon1 for image1,icon2 for image2,icon3 for image3 and so on  for  for that dragged image in <div>2 not the dragged image. then move the dragged image in <div>3.

Comment: It'd be good to put that comment into the question.

Comment: thank you. Please help me to fine the solution .I am new to stack overflow